# How to decode "secureTextEntry" textinput in react native

Tags: react-native, passwords, textfield

I am using `TextInput` in react native. There is a property `secureTextEntry` for password type.

Problem is, that this field returns dots in `onChangeText` function instead of my text -> `••••••••••••a`

How can I decode this string?

I need to send this password into my server `POST /login` route, but I can't because it is hiden with dots.

Answer (score 1):

use the TextInput like in the example below, you should not have problems..

```
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

 <TextInput
  placeholder="Password"
  secureTextEntry={true}
  onChangeText={setPassword}
  {password}
 </TextInput>
```